# Limit result in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

How to limit the number of rows returned in NHibernate?

I am looking for something like [SetMaxResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568865/limiting-number-of-results-when-using-nhibernate)(), but couldn't find it in Nhibernate namespace!

**Note: I want to use `NHibernate.Criterion`, not `NHibernate.IQuery`, so it's best if you can provide that example.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can just use

```
public void GetByCriteria(ICriterion criterion)
{
var criteria= ISession.CreateCiteria(typeof(T)).SetMaxResults(maxResult);
criteria.Add(criterion);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a SetMaxResults method for ICriteria.